# How do I preserve relative URLs when moving inline JavaScript from a razor view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I'm moving some scripts from an mvc view to a typescript file.

All is going fine but I have a question: normally inside the view I have

```
    url: "~/H3g/PrezzoTerminale/" + promoId,
```

and the `~` is parsed by the razor engine, but if I move in the typescript file, and in the external JS file that typescript generates, how can be sure that the address is always translated?

Just removing the `~` usually creates me problems if i move this in a subdirectory.

Comment: `~` - it point on root folder of web application, if you remove this then path `"/H3g/PrezzoTerminale/"` will be relative root of site, without any subfolders, `"H3g/PrezzoTerminale/"` - path relative current position

Comment: I cannot assume that any reference to extenal links, like webservices are in a subdirectory of the .js file.
From my tests, if I move the application in a subdirectory of the site and use "/H3g/PrezzoTerminale/" the path is relative to root of the site, and not the root of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should place this at the bottom of your view.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/test/")
```

here test is the url of your typescript file.

If it helps then marks it, So that it will helps others.

Comment: the url is inside the .js file, I'm moving from the razor view to the external js file.

Answer (score 0):

as workaround you can create js variable in your page or layout like this

```
var _root = '@Url.Content("~/")';
```

and then use it in script like

```
var url = _root + "H3g/PrezzoTerminale/";
```